# Getting error "exceeded available parameter key space"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails application, after form post, getting error `exceeded available parameter key space`. there are too many form fields inside form. Is that reason for error?
Any views?

Comment: what is the form action if it's a get try to make post

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122411/rails-javascript-too-many-parameter-keys-whats-a-good-way-to-normalize-f

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you really need it badly try increasing the `key_space_limit`

```
Rack::Utils.key_space_limit = 262144
```

But this can be dangerous as per [this](https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/318) "A higher exposure to POST parsing DOS attacks."

Check this

https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/318

[Rails / javascript: "too many parameter keys" - what's a good way to normalize form data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122411/rails-javascript-too-many-parameter-keys-whats-a-good-way-to-normalize-f)

http://myrailsway.blogspot.in/2012/04/rangeerror-exceeded-available-parameter.html

Answer (score 0):

If you specified a submission method other than POST (such as `method: :get`) you might have to make your form submit a POST request instead.