# Error: exceeded available parameter key space

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In order to fix this issue, I have found answers like increase the Rack key space limit

From this link
[Getting error "exceeded available parameter key space"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243694/getting-error-exceeded-available-parameter-key-space)

it saying increase the limit as 
Rack::Utils.key_space_limit = 262144

Im still getting same issue in my production server
Can I increase the limit to a bigger value?

I have found a similar answer in the below link,
http://myrailsway.blogspot.in/2012/04/rangeerror-exceeded-available-parameter.html

Can I proceed with this bigger value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem while trying to upload an image through the key space. I read something that helped me. You have to create a file in config/initializers that contains the following:

```
if Rack::Utils.respond_to?("key_space_limit=")
  Rack::Utils.key_space_limit = 68719476736
end
```

My file is called rack_initializer.rb. What this does is increase the size of the key space so that you can transfer a larger parameter. The answer to your question is yes you can.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi @Dias if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: yeah, I increased the key_space limit to a bigger value, and its working ....Thanks againg

Comment: @nkipreos, a key_space_limit of 64GB huge. Apart from being vulnerable to possible DDOS attack, have you had any issues from bumping the key_space_limit that high?

Comment: I haven't had any issues with this. It is true it would be better using some approach such as uploading the file to S3 and referencing it with a url, but if you want to upload to your server, this is an option. Obviously, there are many others. If your main concern is being vulnerable against DDOS attacks I would suggest using something as AWS Shield or WAF, because, depending on the magnitude of the attack, chances are that you'll be affected independently of the key_space_limit. I would sugest further reading of https://aws.amazon.com/es/answers/networking/aws-ddos-attack-mitigation/. Cheers