# Cordova ajax call fail on real device and works in the emulator

Tags: ajax, cordova

I have a Cordova application with some Ajax calls. Everything works fine but a call where I upload some picture taken through the camera (via base64 encoding).

The problem is that on the Genymotion emulator (Nexus 5) the call works fine, on the other hand on a real Nexus 5 the call fails with error 500 and I really can't figure out why.

Here's the code of the Ajax call:

```
 $('.add-coupon').on('click', function() {
    var dt = {
        "api_token": localStorage['api_token'],
        "title": localStorage['c_title'],
        "description": localStorage['c_description'],
        "start_price": localStorage['c_price'],
        "third_level_category": localStorage['c_third'],
        "main_attachments": localStorage['image_0'],
        "post_attachments_1": localStorage['image_1'],
        "post_attachments_2": localStorage['image_2'],
        "post_attachments_3": localStorage['image_3']
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com:8000/api/v1/upload',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(dt),
        cache: true,
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            alert('ok');
            window.location = 'index-shop.html';
        },
        error: function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
            alert('[event:' + event + '], [jqXHR:' + jqXHR.responseText + '], [ajaxSettings:' + ajaxSettings + '], [thrownError:' + thrownError + '])');
        }
    });
 });
```

As you can see nothing special happens during the request, what am I missing?

If I make the call with the same data even with postman (the chrome plugin) everything works fine!

EDIT: If I do NOT take any picture (so main_attachmends and all the post_attachments are empty) the call works. It's only when i take the images that do not work.

Comment: If you are using a device that is outside the network.so that's why you will get the error.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean with "outside the network"? And why all the other ajax calls work fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding this code: [Getting error "exceeded available parameter key space"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243694/getting-error-exceeded-available-parameter-key-space)

Apparently the emulator images were really small and everything worked fine, but with normal images i get the following error:

```
App 15424 stderr: [ 2015-05-04 13:28:38.2529 15508/0x00000001a22140(Worker 1) utils.rb:84 ]: *** Exception RangeError in Rack application object (exceeded available parameter key space) (process 15508, thread 0x00000001a22140(Worker 1))
```