# Ruby Sinatra - Range Error with large-ish json payload in post request

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I am building a small Sinatra API that will run some calculations and store results on the server. The POST route requires a JSON payload. The JSON payload is a combination of floats, arrays of floats and base64 encoded data.

This is the route

```
post '/calc' do
  rad_data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  # Perform calculations
end
```

Everything works fine when the `json` is around 2.8MB, but when the size gets to 3.9MB I receive the error

```
2021-11-20 17:33:43 +0000 Rack app ("POST /calc" - (78.110.164.58)): #<RangeError: RangeError>
```

(It is also weird that `78.110.164.58` is not the ip address of the machine and i have no idea where it comes from.)

The structure of the payload is exactly the same. The larger one has simply longer arrays. Also, if I load the file directly on the server everything works, so it is not a problem with the json content.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122411/rails-javascript-too-many-parameter-keys-whats-a-good-way-to-normalize-f) answer I have added the `key_space_limit` to the beginning of the app, but it makes no difference.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'
require 'rack'
if Rack::Utils.respond_to?("key_space_limit=")
  puts "Yes"
  Rack::Utils.key_space_limit = 2**64 
end
```

Just in case it helps, I send my request with Ruby `rest-client`

```
RestClient.post(uri_post, JSON.dump(rad_data))
```

Comment: When you say "if I load the file directly on the server everything works", do you mean that you can load the file using  an IRB console? Also, which Ruby server are you using? Are you using a reverse proxy? If so, which one?